# Unity RPC not being called

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have been bashing my head against this RPC call for a few hours now, and despite extensive googling I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

At the moment, I am doing all testing within unity editor, (player set to run in background if that matters).

For some reason, my RPC call isn't going through.

There is a lot of stuff going on in the code, so the only important bit (I think) is:

```
public void GenerateDungeon()
{
    Debug.Log ("GENERATING DUNGEON");
    tiles = dungeon.SetDungeonData();

    //Begin looking through every single tile
    for(int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; i++)
    {   
        //If our tile is something useful, aka not a void area in the dungeon
        if(tiles[i] != 0){

            //Bogus location
            int x = 0;
            int z = 0;

            //Real World Location
            convert.ConvertIndexToXY(i,ref x,ref z);

            //Wouldn't need if I understood the math, but since I don't being extra careful
            int leftTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x-1,z)];
            int rightTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x+1,z)];
            int topTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x,z-1)];
            int bottomTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x,z+1)];

            //Create a base layer for compairing dungeon
            CreateDebugDungeon(x,z);

            //Determine what we are trying to spawn, and spawn it
            if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.Corner)
                CheckCorners(leftTile, rightTile, topTile, bottomTile, x, z, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

            if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.OneWall)
                CheckOneWalls(leftTile, rightTile, topTile, bottomTile, x, z, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

            if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof)
                CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof, x,z,0,dungeonWidth,dungeonHeight);

            if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.Corridor)
                CheckCorridors(leftTile, rightTile, topTile, bottomTile, x, z, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);    
        }//end if tiles != 0
    }//end for

    Debug.Log ("Done pushing tiles");
    //networkView.RPC("SpawnCharacter",RPCMode.AllBuffered, team1Spawn);
    networkView.RPC ("SpawnCharacter",RPCMode.All);
    //networkView.RPC ("Merp",RPCMode.All);
    //networkView.RPC ("PushTiles",RPCMode.All);
    //Debug.Log ("Merr?");

}//end generate dungeon

[RPC]
void SpawnCharacter()
{
    Debug.Log ("Spawning character at : " );
    //Instantiate(character,position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

At the moment, this should only be called server side.

Here is the full code for the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
/// <summary>
/// BSP Spawning Script is responsible creating a dungeon from scratch to finished.
/// </summary>
public class BSPSpawningScript : MonoBehaviour{

public int dungeonWidth = 80;
public int dungeonHeight = 80;
public int numSplits = 4;
public GameObject character;
public float charYOffset;

short[] tiles;

BSPDungeon dungeon;
CoConvert convert;
bool team1  = false;
bool team2 = false;
GameObject lastTile;
Vector3 team1Spawn;

void Start()
{
    if(Network.isClient)
    {
        GameObject.Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Debug.Log ("Destroying");   
    }

    convert = new CoConvert(dungeonWidth);
    dungeon = new BSPDungeon(dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);
    dungeon.treeData.SplitNodes(numSplits);
    dungeon.GenerateRooms ();
    dungeon.GenerateCorridors();
    GenerateDungeon();
}

public void Reset()
{
    dungeon.Reset();
    dungeon.treeData.SplitNodes(numSplits);
    dungeon.GenerateRooms ();
    dungeon.GenerateCorridors();
    GenerateDungeon();
}

public void GenerateDungeon()
{
    Debug.Log ("GENERATING DUNGEON");
    tiles = dungeon.SetDungeonData();

    //Begin looking through every single tile
    for(int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; i++)
    {   
        //If our tile is something useful, aka not a void area in the dungeon
        if(tiles[i] != 0){

        //Bogus location
        int x = 0;
        int z = 0;

        //Real World Location
        convert.ConvertIndexToXY(i,ref x,ref z);

        //Wouldn't need if I understood the math, but since I don't being extra careful
        int leftTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x-1,z)];
        int rightTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x+1,z)];
        int topTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x,z-1)];
        int bottomTile = tiles[convert.ConvertXYToIndex(x,z+1)];

        //Create a base layer for compairing dungeon
        CreateDebugDungeon(x,z);

        //Determine what we are trying to spawn, and spawn it
        if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.Corner)
            CheckCorners(leftTile, rightTile, topTile, bottomTile, x, z, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.OneWall)
            CheckOneWalls(leftTile, rightTile, topTile, bottomTile, x, z, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof, x,z,0,dungeonWidth,dungeonHeight);

        if(tiles[i] == (short)Enums.TileType.Corridor)
            CheckCorridors(leftTile, rightTile, topTile, bottomTile, x, z, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);    
        }//end if tiles != 0
    }//end for

    Debug.Log ("Done pushing tiles");
    //networkView.RPC("SpawnCharacter",RPCMode.AllBuffered, team1Spawn);
    networkView.RPC ("SpawnCharacter",RPCMode.All);
    //networkView.RPC ("Merp",RPCMode.All);
    //networkView.RPC ("PushTiles",RPCMode.All);
    //Debug.Log ("Merr?");

}//end generate dungeon

[RPC]
void SpawnCharacter()
{
    Debug.Log ("Spawning character at : " );
    //Instantiate(character,position, Quaternion.identity);
}

/// <summary>
/// Create Tile is responsible for instantiating tiles.  
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tileType">What Tile type to spawn.</param>
/// <param name="x">The x coordinate to spawn tile at.</param>
/// <param name="z">The z coordinate to spawn tile at.</param>
/// <param name="rotation">What rotation to spawn the tile at.</param>
/// <param name="dungeonWidth">Dungeon width.</param>
/// <param name="dungeonHeight">Dungeon height.</param>
public void CreateTile(int tileType, int x, int z, float rotation, int dungeonWidth, int dungeonHeight)
{
    //So it displays right-side up in the center of the scene
    x -= dungeonWidth/2;
    z -= dungeonHeight/2;

    //Offsetting for the tile size
    x *= 8;
    z *= -8;

    //Set up temporary object
    GameObject tempObject;

    //Get it's position
    Vector3 tempPos = new Vector3(x,0,z);

    bool sendSpawn = false;

    switch(tileType)
    {
        case -1:
            Debug.Log ("NONE FOUND " + tempPos);
            tempObject = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Error"));
            break;
        case (int)Enums.TileType.Corner:
            tempObject = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Corner"));
            break;
        case (int)Enums.TileType.OneWall:
            tempObject = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("OneWall"));
            break;
        case (int)Enums.TileType.Doorway:
            tempObject = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Doorway"));
            break;
        case (int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof:
            tempObject =(GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("FloorAndRoof"));
        if(team1 == false)
            {
                //character.transform.position = new Vector3(x, charYOffset,z);
                //GameObject.Find"      
                team1Spawn = new Vector3(x, charYOffset, z);        
                team1 = true;
                sendSpawn = true;
                Debug.Log ("SETTING SPAWN");
            }
            break;
    case (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor:
        tempObject =(GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Corridor"));
        break;
    default:
        tempObject = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load ("Error"));
        Debug.Log ("DEFAULT " + tempPos);
        break;
    }

    tempObject.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0f, rotation, 0f));
    tempObject.transform.position = tempPos;


    //TESTING
    networkView.RPC ("PushTile", RPCMode.AllBuffered, tempObject, tempPos, rotation);

    //GameObject.Destroy (tempObject);
}

[RPC]
void PushTile(GameObject tileObject, Vector3 tilePosition, float rotation)
{
    Debug.Log ("Rawr");
    GameObject objectCopy = tileObject;
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, rotation, 0f);
    Network.Instantiate(objectCopy, tilePosition, newRotation, 0);
}

/// <summary>
/// Determins which direction a tile should face, as a corner.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="leftTile">The tile to the left of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="rightTile">The tile to the right of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="topTile">The tile ontop of the target tile</param>
/// <param name="bottomTile">The tile below the target tile</param>
/// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="dungeonWidth">Dungeon width.</param>
/// <param name="dungeonHeight">Dungeon height.</param>
public void CheckCorners (int leftTile, int rightTile, int topTile, int bottomTile, int x, int z, int dungeonWidth, int dungeonHeight)
{
    //Left And Top Empty = NW
    //Left and Bottom Empty = SW
    //Right and Top Empty = NE
    //Right and Bottom Empty = NW

    if(leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
    {
        if(topTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Corner,x,z,(float)Enums.CornerDirections.NorthWest, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Corner,x,z,(float)Enums.CornerDirections.SouthWest, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else
            CreateTile(-1,x,z,0, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);
    }
    else if(rightTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
    {
        if(topTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Corner,x,z,(float)Enums.CornerDirections.NorthEast, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Corner,x,z,(float)Enums.CornerDirections.SouthEast, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else
            CreateTile(-1,x,z,0, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);              
    }
else
    CreateTile(-1,x,z,0, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Determins which direction a tile should face, as a single wall.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="leftTile">The tile to the left of the target tile.</param>
    /// <param name="rightTile">The tile to the right of the target tile.</param>
    /// <param name="topTile">The tile ontop of the target tile</param>
    /// <param name="bottomTile">The tile below the target tile</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the target tile.</param>
    /// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the target tile.</param>
    /// <param name="dungeonWidth">Dungeon width.</param>
    /// <param name="dungeonHeight">Dungeon height.</param>
    public void CheckOneWalls(int leftTile, int rightTile, int topTile, int bottomTile, int x, int z, int dungeonWidth, int dungeonHeight)
    {       
        if(bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof && topTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.OneWall, x,z,(float)Enums.OneWallDirections.North, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof && rightTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.OneWall, x,z,(float)Enums.OneWallDirections.East, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(rightTile == (int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof && leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.OneWall, x,z,(float)Enums.OneWallDirections.West, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(topTile == (int)Enums.TileType.FloorAndRoof && bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Empty)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.OneWall, x,z,(float)Enums.OneWallDirections.South, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Doorway, x,z,(float)Enums.DoorwayDirections.South, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(topTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Doorway, x,z,(float)Enums.DoorwayDirections.North, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Doorway, x,z,(float)Enums.DoorwayDirections.West, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else if(rightTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor)
            CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Doorway, x,z,(float)Enums.DoorwayDirections.East, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

        else
            CreateTile(-1, x,z,0, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);
}

/// <summary>
/// Determins which direction a tile should face, as a corridor.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="leftTile">The tile to the left of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="rightTile">The tile to the right of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="topTile">The tile ontop of the target tile</param>
/// <param name="bottomTile">The tile below the target tile</param>
    /// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the target tile.</param>
/// <param name="dungeonWidth">Dungeon width.</param>
/// <param name="dungeonHeight">Dungeon height.</param>
public void CheckCorridors(int leftTile, int rightTile, int topTile, int bottomTile, int x, int z, int dungeonWidth, int dungeonHeight)
{
    //We are a N/S corridor IF our bottom tile is a...
    //Doorway, corridor, or a single wall (because sometimes we are checked before walls have become doorways)
    if(bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Doorway || bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor || bottomTile == (int)Enums.TileType.OneWall)
        CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Corridor, x,z,(float)Enums.CorridorDirections.NorthSouth, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

    //We are a W/E corridor IF our bottom tile is a...
    //Doorway, corridor, or a single wall (because sometimes we are checked before walls have become doorways)
    else if(leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Doorway || leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.Corridor || leftTile == (int)Enums.TileType.OneWall)
        CreateTile((int)Enums.TileType.Corridor, x,z,(float)Enums.CorridorDirections.WestEast, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);

    else
        CreateTile(-1, x,z,0, dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight);
}

/// <summary>
/// Create Debug Dungeon is responible for creating a flat dungeon underneathe (-2 y) the real dungeon.
/// This is for testing only and should not be included in the final product.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">The x coordinate of the tile to create.</param>
/// <param name="z">The z coordinate of the tile to create.</param>
public void CreateDebugDungeon(int x, int z)
{
    //So it displays right-side up in the center of the scene
    x -= dungeonWidth/2;
    z -= dungeonHeight/2;

    //Offsetting for the tile size
    x *= 8;
    z *= -8;

    GameObject tempObjectDebug = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("TestSubject"));
    tempObjectDebug.transform.position = new Vector3(x, -2, z);
}
```

}

After all is said and done, the console will print:
GENERATING DUNGEON
SETTING DUNGEON DATA
SETTING SPAWN
Done pushing tiles

The character reference is set up correctly, the tiles are being instantiated correctly, everything seems to be working as intended, with the exception of the RPC call being ignored? There are no errors, no warnings.

I appreciate any help anyone can give, 
Tiffany

Comment: There is some debate on which site is better in this case: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254080/can-we-move-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-codereview-se/254085#254085 but I'm sure a Mod will chime in before too much longer.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Code Review is for reviewing code that **works as expected**.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Code Review only reviews working code, as is very clearly stated in the [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).